# Add hyphen in a string after every 2 characters using in mysql select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table with some data. In that i have a column(mobile_number) and that column value is like mobile number (ex:1234587920).

my expected out put is : 12-34-58-79-20

I want to add hyphen after every two numbers.

Comment: That ain't a comma

Comment: It seems much smarter to do this kind of thing in the presentation layer

Answer (score 3):

use concat() for joining strings and use substr() for split a string in mysql :

split (column,start,count) select column from start position for count charachter

concat(column1,"-",column2) will be column1-column2

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(phone,1,2),'-',SUBSTR(phone,3,2),'-',SUBSTR(phone,5,2),'- 
',SUBSTR(phone,7,2),'-',SUBSTR(phone,9,2)) FROM `table`
```

Comment: dont be judge . Not at all

Comment: thankyou  esnkrimi.....And i would like to ask one more doubt ..if i don't know  how many numbers i have (i.e string length) as of now i have 10 digits,So i am putting as static but if it's dynamic what would be the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely use `concat_ws()` for this:

```
select concat_ws('-',
                 substr(mobile_number, 1, 2),
                 substr(mobile_number, 3, 2),
                 substr(mobile_number, 5, 2),
                 substr(mobile_number, 7, 2)
                )
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48dacfd0f67cbc9a5366d82b2dff82b5) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT concat(SUBSTRING("1234587920", 1, 2),"-",SUBSTRING("1234587920",3,2),"- 
",SUBSTRING("1234587920", 5, 2),"-",
SUBSTRING("1234587920", 7, 2),"-",
SUBSTRING("1234587920", 9, 2)) AS ExtractString;
```

for your table query is like :

```
SELECT concat(SUBSTRING(mobile_number, 1, 2),"- 
",SUBSTRING(mobile_number,3,2),"-",SUBSTRING(mobile_number, 5, 2),"-",
SUBSTRING(mobile_number, 7, 2),"-",
SUBSTRING(mobile_number, 9, 2)) ExtractString from tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use substr and contact_ws command in mysql

```
update tmp_pay SET   date_fix  = concat_ws('-',substr(date_at,1,4),substr(date_at,5,6),'01') ;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
select concat( right(phone_number,3) , "-" , mid(phone_number,4,3) , "-", right(phone_number,4)) from table
```